# What is the shorthand when a ternary tests for greater than/less than condition?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

If I have a ternary that is testing for a greater than/less than condition and that value is then assigned back to the original variable, is there short hand for that?

```
var firstVar = 1
var secondVar = 2
firstVar = firstVar > secondVar ? firstVar : secondVar
```

Is there a simpler way to write line 3?

Comment: Isn't the current code already a shortcut?

Comment: How do you imagine this being shorter?

Comment: sure but still seems like there could be a simpler way to make this comparison and assignment

Comment: `firstVar = Math.max(firstVar, secondVar)` might be literally shorter, but I'm not sure if it 's faster ...

Comment: You can replace the third line with `firstVar > secondVar ? '' : firstVar = secondVar;`. Not shorter actually but will skip the reassignment in case firstVar is the greater one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of another possible one-liner shortcut for your test, using `||` operator (logical OR).

```js
var firstVar = 1;
var secondVar = 2;
firstVar > secondVar || (firstVar = secondVar);
console.log(firstVar);
```

Basically, expression on third line returns `true`, if first operand is evaluated as `true` (whole expression will return "truthy" return value of expression in first operand in general). Otherwise, it will return expression in second operand (return value of variable assignment in this case). However, return value of this whole expression isn't assigned to any variable, because goal was only to perform specific assignment (second operand), if given condition (first operand) wasn't satisfied.

Also, this method might not be as intuitive as simple `if` statement, because variable assignment can only happen, if condition in first operand is **not** satisfied. It will work like variable assignment in `else` statement after empty `if` statement from previous answer. Or you can inverse statement in first operand, if this pattern is not matching your original logic.

Note: Variable assignment in second operand has to be in parentheses, because it has lower precedence than logical OR. You might want to check this table on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table), if you are not sure about precedence of operators while constructing expressions.

Comment: @Dummy 'unreadable code' is any code you haven't read before, by not spreading it you are keeping it unreadable, i asked for this, stop telling people to stop answering questions

Comment: thanks, i like this version because it's actually what i was looking for, a shorthand way sort of like `var thing = thing || {}`

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Even the OP said his answer is not as intuitive as a simple `if` statement, unreadable code means code that is hard to understand and clearly you don't even know what unreadable code means :)

Comment: @Dummy js is not my first language, if you can't read this then ok, good luck

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Same for everyone else. What I said initially is the things you will hear in a code review, so no surprise if you have had a code review before

Comment: @Dummy ok zealot

Comment: @Dummy I have provided this answer because I thought it might be a possible shortcut for given expression the OP was looking for (possibly without reassignment of variable with its previous value). I can agree with you that readability of this expression might be an issue (althought I occasionally find it viable for assigning some sort of default value of variables / function arguments which have to have restricted range of possible values).

Comment: @MKL I didn't say you couldn't give answer, what I meant was your answer is a bad one because it is unreadable and not even shorter than the other answer, and promoting unreadable code is bad, just like many other bad answers on here that are down voted even though I didn't down vote yours because I don't do that

Answer (score 2):

I will go with a simple `if` statement which only assigns the value if the condition is `true`.

```js
var firstVar = 1;
var secondVar = 2;
if (firstVar <= secondVar) firstVar = secondVar;
console.log(firstVar);
```